# How to fetch count from relationshipe table in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have driver's has many relation with `run_sheets` and runsheet can `hasMany` relation with `consignments`

Driver model

```
 public function run_sheets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Admin\RunSheet','driver_id');
    }
```

runsheet model

```
  public function consignments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Admin\Consignment', 'runsheet_id')->orderBy('delivery_address');
    }
```

so in order to take count of conisgnments i have to use loops which increase the number of queries and page gets slow down

```
 @foreach($driver->run_sheets as $run_sheet)

 @php $total_consignments +=$run_sheet->consignments()->where('delivery_date','=',$date)->where('delivery_date','!=',null)->whereIn('is_group',['parent',null])->count(); @endphp
@endforeach
                                {{$total_consignments}}
```

is there any way i can do this by query efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [has many through](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) and [aggregating](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#aggregating-related-models) to do this. First  define has many through relationship in Driver model:

```
public function consignments() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Admin\Consignment', 'App\Models\Admin\RunSheet','driver_id','runsheet_id')->orderBy('delivery_address');
}
```

Count query:

```
$drivers = Driver::withCount([
    'consignments as consignment_count' => function ($query) use ($date) {
        $query->where('delivery_date', '=', $date)->where('delivery_date', '!=', null)->whereIn('is_group', ['parent', null]);
    }])
    ->get();
```

in blade:

```
@foreach($drivers as $driver)
    {{$driver->consignment_count}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: giving error `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'consignments' (SQL: select `drivers`.*, (select count(*) from `consignments` inner join `consignments` on `consignments`.`id` = `consignments`.`runsheet_id` where `drivers`.`id` = `consignments`.`driver_id` and `delivery_date` = 2021-05-06 and `delivery_date` is not null and `is_group` in (parent, ?)) as `consignment_count` from `drivers`) (View: C:\projects\coldxlogistics\resources\views\web\admin\partials\drivers\driver_consignments_statistics.blade.php)
http://localhost:8000/drivers/show/21`

Comment: relationship between Driver and Consignment is many to many?

Comment: relation is between run_sheet and driver..and each consignment belongsTo runsheet

Comment: my bad, I have updated the consignments relationship in Driver  model